# Record Selenium interaction with API in custom format

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to record user interaction with the website, I know that Selenium IDE can do such things, but I want to save the result in JSON with a specific format, is there a way that I can do that with Python and  API?

I expected mostly the same as Selenium IDE can do: after I run my .py file, it opens a webdriver and I do some actions, then it saves the result in a specific custom JSON format. I searched a lot but most of them tell me to use Selenium IDE but it doesn't seem that Selenium IDE has such a feature...